# Help with Ubuntu 1604 pressed.cfg with multiple partitioning scheme

Tags: grub2, partitioning, kernel, preseed

Hi I am trying to automate my ubuntu installation by using packer and a pressed.cfg file. For the resulting VM I want my file system to have /boot on sda1 and rest all on sda2.
For e.g

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2        30G  9.8G   20G  34% /
....
/dev/sda1       114M   32M   74M  30% /boot
tmpfs           394M     0  394M   0% /run/user/0
```

I am using the following pressed.cfg file
    d-i debian-installer/locale string en_US

```
d-i console-setup/ask_detect boolean false
d-i keyboard-configuration/xkb-keymap select us

d-i netcfg/get_hostname string *****
d-i netcfg/get_domain string *****

# Disable that annoying WEP key dialog.
d-i netcfg/wireless_wep string


d-i mirror/http/mirror select us.archive.ubuntu.com
choose-mirror-bin mirror/http/proxy string

d-i passwd/root-password password ********
d-i passwd/root-password-again password ********


d-i passwd/user-fullname string ***** Base
d-i passwd/username string *****

d-i passwd/user-password password *****
d-i passwd/user-password-again password *****


d-i user-setup/encrypt-home boolean false
d-i clock-setup/utc boolean true
d-i time/zone string UTC
d-i clock-setup/ntp boolean true

### Partitioning

d-i partman-auto/disk string /dev/sda
d-i partman-auto/method string regular
d-i partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm boolean true
d-i partman-md/device_remove_md boolean true
d-i partman/default_filesystem string ext4
d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string                         \
      boot-root ::                                            \
              40 50 100 ext4                                  \
                      $primary{ } $bootable{ }                \
                      method{ format } format{ }              \
                      use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
                      mountpoint{ /boot }                     \
              .                                               \
              500 10000 1000000000 ext4                       \
                      method{ format } format{ }              \
                      use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
                      mountpoint{ / }                         \
              .                                               \
              64 512 300% linux-swap                          \
                      method{ swap } format{ }                \
              .

  d-i partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
  d-i partman/choose_partition select finish
  d-i partman/confirm boolean true
  d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true


tasksel tasksel/first multiselect standard, ubuntu-server
d-i pkgsel/include string  openssh-server build-essential
d-i pkgsel/update-policy select unattended-upgrades
d-i grub-installer/only_debian boolean true
d-i grub-installer/with_other_os boolean true
d-i finish-install/reboot_in_progress note
d-i preseed/late_command string \
    sed -i -e 's/^#\?PasswordAuthentication.*/PasswordAuthentication yes/g' /target/etc/ssh/sshd_config;\
    sed -i -e 's/^#\?PermitRootLogin.*/PermitRootLogin yes/g' /target/etc/ssh/sshd_config;\
    sed -i 's/^GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0/GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=5/' /target/etc/default/grub ;\
    sed -i 's/^GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true/GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=false/' /target/etc/default/grub
```

When i run the installation I get following filesystem setup.
    Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
    /dev/root        30G  9.8G   20G  34% /
    ....
    /dev/sda1       114M   32M   74M  30% /boot
    tmpfs           394M     0  394M   0% /run/user/0

What am I missing causing the rest of the file system to be on /dev/root?

Also during the installation it gives a manual prompt that it failed to installed linux-generic package. Exact error message:
 Unable to install selected kernel. An error occurred to installed Linux Kernel into target system. Kernel package : linux-generic.

It says to see syslog but not sure how I can get there during installation. 
And to move it forward I end up selecting "initrd" > generic include all available drivers. 
That prompt says "the primary function of initrd is to allow kernel to mount root file system"

What do I need to do to get rid of this prompt?

Update:
I got rid of the manual prompt. The issue was my boot partition minimum size was small. When I increased to 100 megs then it worked.

parted config that worked :

```
d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string                         \
      boot-root ::                                            \
              100 50 200 ext4                                  \
                      $primary{ } $bootable{ }                \
                      method{ format } format{ }              \
                      use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
                      mountpoint{ /boot }                     \
              .                                               \
              500 10000 1000000000 ext4                       \
                      method{ format } format{ }              \
                      use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
                      label{ /dev/sda2 }                      \
                      mountpoint{ / }                         \
              .                                               \
              64 512 300% linux-swap                          \
                      method{ swap } format{ }                \
              .
```

Now when the installation finishes I see following in the filesystems that are mounted:

```
df -h    
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            983M     0  983M   0% /dev
tmpfs           201M  3.2M  197M   2% /run
/dev/sda5       9.2G  1.5G  7.3G  17% /
tmpfs          1001M     0 1001M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs          1001M     0 1001M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1        88M   52M   29M  65% /boot
tmpfs           201M     0  201M   0% /run/user/1000
```

Still not sure why rest of file system is on /dev/sda5 and not /dev/sda2.

Disk output:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 10 GiB, 10737418240 bytes, 20971520 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x37673233

Device     Boot    Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *        2048   194559   192512   94M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2         196606 20969471 20772866  9.9G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5         196608 20049919 19853312  9.5G 83 Linux
/dev/sda6       20051968 20969471   917504  448M 82 Linux swap / Solaris
```

Not sure where that extended partition is coming from. Any way to get rid of it?

Comment: Update: I got rid of the manual prompt. The issue was my /boot partition was small and hence base kernel install could not be done. When I increased it to be minimum of 100 then it worked without prompt.

Comment: If you solved your problem yourself, please [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) and accept it. Don’t put the answer in your question or the comments! Send me a message in the comments if you want my up-vote. :-)

Comment: My question is not yet resolved. I still get some partitions created that I don't want while using pressed file.

Answer (score 0):

The following configuration worked for me:

```
d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string                         \
      boot-root ::                                            \
              200 50 300 ext4                                  \
                      $primary{ } $bootable{ }                \
                      method{ format } format{ }              \
                      use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
                      mountpoint{ /boot }                     \
              .                                               \
              500 10000 4096 ext4                            \
                      $primary{ }                             \
                      method{ format } format{ }              \
                      use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
                      mountpoint{ / }                         \
              .                                               \

d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe select boot-root
```

It now creates the partitions that I want.